# Fastify redirect to external URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, fastify

Using `fastify` library I want to be redirected to a web-page.
Looking at all the examples in docs, it seems like it covers only route-to-route redirection.

[Link to redirect docs](https://www.fastify.io/docs/v2.6.x/Reply/#redirectdest)

```
fastify.post('/v1/launch', async (req, res) => {
  response.redirect('/empty-cart');
});
```

The code above results in 404 error trying to find that route.

[image: result]

But how it can be redirected to external page? Thanks!

**Update**:
Trying to redirect to `https://my-domain.com/empty-cart`

[image: result2]

with `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error

Comment: `response.redirect('https://example.com');`

Comment: @0stone0 question is updated. still not working

Comment: If you enter https://my-domain.com/empty-cart in your browser do you get anything or a 404?

Comment: @Frazer look update above

Comment: I mean if you go to https : //my-domain.com/empty-cart directly, not via a redirection.

Comment: @Frazer it opens :)

Comment: Is it a typo? Res argument vs response in code snippet

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
response.redirect('https://stackoverflow.com/')
```

Docs: https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Reply/#redirectcode--dest

Comment: this redirects to `https://old-domain.com/https://new-domain.com`